# let $A$ and $B$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$, problem about their join:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ which has order $p^2$ where $p$ is a prime.
Define the join: $A \vee B$.  The join of $A$ and $B$ is the intersection of all subgroups that contain $AB$

Assume $A \cap B = (e)$ the identity.

Now I couldn't understand the following statement:

> Now, $A\vee B$ is a subgroup of $G$ properly containing $A$ and of order dividing $p^2$. Hence  $A\vee B=G$.

How come?

Comment: What is "the joint: AVB"?

Comment: @ZainPatel The join of $A$ and $B$ is the intersection of all subgroups that contain $AB$

Comment: "How come" what? Do you not understand the first sentence, the second sentence, or the connection between them?

Comment: @StellaBiderman I wanted to see a precise explanation for the situtation. That is likely caused due to my imperfection on the subject. Which is pretty normal for someone interested in mathematics, I believe it has nothing to do with "understanding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't understand the statement because, without additional assumptions, it is false. Indeed, take $A=\{e\}=B$: then the join of $A$ and $B$ is obviously $\{e\}$.

If you assume $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of order $p$, then it's a different thing. And you don't need the subgroups to be normal in order to show $A\vee B=G$. Indeed, $A\vee B$ properly contains $A$, so its order must be greater than $p$ and the only divisor of $p^2$ greater than $p$ is $p^2$.

Note that the standard definition of join is: $A\vee B$ is the intersection of all subgroups containing both $A$ and $B$ (it can be shown it is also the intersection of all subgroups containing $AB$, actually). In the case *one* of them is normal, then $A\vee B=AB$.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's theorem, you have that $ p = |A| $ divides $ |A \lor B| $, which divides $ |G| = p^2 $. Therefore, the only choices for $ |A \lor B| $ are $ p $ and $ p^2 $, however since the inclusion $ A \subset A \lor B $ is proper, $ |A \lor B| \neq p $. It follows that $ |A \lor B| = p^2 $, i.e $ A \lor B = G $.

Comment: The easy answer to this is just that $A\lor B= AB$ since $AB$ is a normal subgroup when $A$ and $B$ are normal. (of course your answer dives into why $AB$ has order $p^2$)